# File transfer between RISCV - Qemu and Host

Tags: qemu

I am following steps provided on

https://www.cnx-software.com/2018/03/16/how-to-run-linux-on-risc-v-with-qemu-emulator/.

and trying to bootup riscv qemu on linux.

I was able to boot the qemu successfully, but now I want to run my own hello world program on riscv-qemu.

I have cross compiled my hello world program using riscv gnu toolchain on my host system, but I am looking for a shared directory to place my executable, so that I can run the compiled code on riscv-qemu after booting it up.

Any help is appreciated. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Glad you found the RISC-V qemu instructions useful.
I also wrote some tutorials about copying files to QEMU either
 1. [Mounting the image](https://www.cnx-software.com/2011/09/29/how-to-transfer-files-between-host-and-qemu/) to add or delete file
 2. [Via a network connection](https://www.cnx-software.com/2011/10/02/how-to-transfer-files-between-host-and-qemu-via-ssh-and-nfs/)

I'm not sure thr RISC-V qemu image supports Ethernet (yet), so the first method may be the only option.

Comment: I don't get much what you trying to do by fdisk -lu overo_sd_alip.img | grep overo, i don't have that image file.

Comment: You need to adapt the instructions to locate the root filesystem in busybear.bin. Mount it, then copy files as needed. Next time you start qemu your file will be there. If networking is enabled, better use the second option.